# Bounding fundamental solution of the pell equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, analytic-number-theory, pell-type-equations

I am looking for the best known upperbound and lowerbound for $m$ in the equation          $m^2 - v(z^2) = 1$ such that $(m,z)$ is the fundamental solution of the pell's equation $x^2 -v(y^2) = 1$.

I.e is it true that the fundamental solution $(m,z)$ satisfies $m < v!$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental solution of Pell's equation $x^2-Dy^2=\pm1$ can be computed from the continued fraction of $\sqrt{D}$ (see [Yang, Theorem 2.6](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Yang.pdf), and [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html)), that by Lagrange's theorem has the following form:
$$ \sqrt{D}=[a,\overline{c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_m,\ldots,c_2,c_1,2a}] \tag{1}$$
so that
$$ \frac{x}{y}=[a,c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_m,\ldots,c_2,c_1] \tag{2} $$
It follows that the size of the fundamental solution depends on the length $\ell$ of the period of the continued fraction of $\sqrt{D}$. Since $c_i\leq a\leq\sqrt{D}$, a bound that is not far from being sharp in many cases is $x\leq D^{\ell/2}$. $\ell$ depends on the [class number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClassNumber.html) of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$, hence
$$ x\leq D^{c\sqrt{D}} \tag{3}$$
for some explicit constant $c$ follows from [Minkowski's bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_bound). So we have that $x\leq D!$ holds for sure for any $D$ large enough.